# How to use CSS to position divs?

Tags: css

I have html that looks roughly like this

```
<div>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <div id="legend"></div>
  <div id="info1"></div>
  <div id="info2"></div>
  <div id="info3"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to position the elements like this: 
[image: positioning]

How in the world do I go about doing this?

**Edit:** This is a question about "the right way to do it" and it is certainly not easily Google-able.  Essentially what I want to do, rather than define columns in html, is to define a height for the container div, and then have the other divs position themselves naturally within it.

Answer (score 6):

Here's something to start with:

**HTML**

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="left-column">
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div id="legend"></div>
</div>
<div id="right-column">
    <div id="info1"></div>
    <div id="info2"></div>
    <div id="info3"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"><!-- --></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#left-column{position:relative;float:left;width:50%;}
#right-column{position:relative;float:right;width:50%;}
.clear{clear:both;}
```

Comment: But you're using html to define columns!  That's hardly guru-ish.  I know there's a way to do it besides that.

Comment: You're asking for how to do something - starting with nothing - and you're complaining that the results are not guru-ish enough? There are quite a few cross-browser issues with floats (mainly ie6) and from what I've seen, most columnar layouts do it this way.

Comment: This is indeed the best way to do it. Have two colums floated left and right and have the relevant DIVs inside them.

Comment: The problem is that you end up injecting layout logic into html.  The columns don't pertain to my structure at all, I am trying to get this page written the 100% right way as a learning exercise.

Comment: There are still many limitations in trying to create pure CSS layouts due to cross-browser compatibility issues and lack of foresight by standards committees. Hopefully after the CSS3 specifications have been finished and are enjoying widespread adoption, we'll be much closer to pure CSS layouts.

Comment: If "guru-ish" means clever -- then are you looking for an answer that uses some JavaScript for positioning the elements based on the view port size?  And if you know there is a better way, post it!  :p

Comment: Why not use the IDs like "content" and "information" or something that doesn't use the word "column"? It doesn't change how to mark up the page, but it might change how you "feel" about it. You're grouping content together either way, which I think is the right thing to be doing in this case.

Comment: Saying you want to do this "the right way" assumes that CSS in practice perfectly matches what it is in theory.  It doesn't; it's a mess and you'll likely have lots more cross-browser difficulties doing it the right way rather than taking shortcuts like grouping in columns, etc.

That said, Jame's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652344/how-to-use-css-to-position-divs/1653230#1653230 looks to be the correct one in this case.  But-- this is two columns.  Try to do the same with three and no containers and "the right way" is going to be more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 4):

You use lots of cool things like `float` and `position`.

Or if you're looking for a solid framework that does most of the work for you, check out [Blueprint CSS](http://www.blueprintcss.org/), which has several grid layouts that you might find applicable.

Here's some more resources you might find useful:

- [15 Extremeley Useful CSS Grid Layouts Generators](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-extremely-useful-css-grid-layout-generator-for-web-designers/)
- [YUI Grids CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/)

Answer (score 4):

The following code will allow you to position your DIV without any additional HTML markup:

```
//* in order to view the results */
div#header, div#chart, div#legend,
div#info1, div#info2, div#info3
{ border: 1px solid black; }

/* IE requirement to center on screen */
body { text-align: center; }

/* define container size */
div
{
 width: 500px;
 margin: auto; 
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
}


/* for header, just define the size */
div#header
{
 width: 500px;
 height: 50px;
}

/* chart and legend are left floating
   and do not allow other elements to their left */
div#chart
{
 width: 248px;
 height: 250px;
 float: left;
 clear: left;
}
div#legend
{
 width: 248px;
 height: 202px;
 float: left;
 clear: left;
}

/* cover the rest with info divs */
div#info1, div#info2, div#info3
{
 width: 248px;
 display: block;
 height: 150px;
 margin-left: 248px;
}
```

You will notice some strange dimension measurements; this is an effort to combat the way browsers treat differently how to measure an element (if they should include the border or not). The final rendering is almost identical to the three browsers I tested (IE8, FF3.5, O10).

Complete test HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

div#header, div#chart, div#legend,
div#info1, div#info2, div#info3
{ border: 1px solid black; }

body { text-align: center; }

div { width: 500px; margin: auto; padding: 0; text-align: center; }

div#header { width: 500px; height: 50px; }
div#chart  { width: 248px; height: 250px; float: left; clear: left; }
div#legend { width: 248px; height: 202px; float: left; clear: left; }

div#info1, div#info2, div#info3
{ width: 248px; display: block; height: 150px; margin-left: 248px; }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="chart">chart</div>
  <div id="legend">legend</div>
  <div id="info1">info1</div>
  <div id="info2">info2</div>
  <div id="info3">info3</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow - awesome.  I think the concept I was missing was the clear style, I did not know about it

Answer (score 2):

### Edit based on Question Edit

Seeing the HTML you have, my biggest suggestion is nesting some of the divs to get the control you want. While I'm not using your specific IDs in my sample below, the nesting should show you how to adapt what you have to where you want to be. (I hope!)

### Original Answer

I'm going to have to make some assumptions about what you're trying to do in order to help you out. Lining up the bottoms will be the single hardest part, so I'm going to just go ahead and pretend it's not really the nice pretty square you've displayed. (I still can't do lining the bottoms without resorting to tables. Although I believe some of the frameworks, like those mentioned in [Josh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652344/how-to-use-css-to-position-divs/1652379#1652379), may be able to make that happen.)

So the assumptions I'm going to make, to keep life relatively simple, are thus:

- You need to have an overarching header
- You need a left column and a right column
- The right column has three discrete elements in it
- The left column has two discrete elements in it

Also to make life easier, I'm not going to break the stylesheets into their own CSS file; I'm going to assume that you know CSS and HTML already, and will be able to move them appropriately based on this basic HTML layout I'm about to throw out there.

So the basic layout would probably look something like such:

```
<html>
    <head><!-- blah blah blah --></head>
    <body>
        <!-- the overall container -->
        <div style="width: 500px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">

            <!-- the header -->
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100px;">
                My headery goodness here
            </div>

            <!-- the left column -->
            <div style="float: left; width: 320px;">
                <div>
                    My charty goodness here
                </div>
                <div>
                    My legendary goodness here
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- the right column -->
            <div style="float: left; width: 180px;">
                <div>
                    Info 1
                </div>
                <div>
                    Info 2
                </div>
                <div>
                    Info 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You'll need to season the dimensions and add `padding` to taste, and if you do want the bottoms to line up, I recommend setting explicit `height`, `min-height`, `max-height` and `overflow` properties on all of the `div`s.

Finally, again, you really want to separate the CSS I've embedded here into appropriate ID or class selectors in a separate CSS file. This was just a rough hash-out to get you started on the layout; it's by no means a complete answer.

Comment: Yeah, I can figure out if I group things by column, but I want to avoid doing that - This is mostly a question of pedagogy but I know it should be possible to get a flow like I showed without any explicit columns

Comment: The only other thing that I think will work, without nested structure, is pure 100% absolute positioning and explicit dimensions.

Comment: I think if you could get your "items that need to layout naturally" described dimensionally (that is to say, if you can define their size up front) then you could float them all and the width of the viewport would create "a" layout.  But it might not necessarily be the most desirable layout.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for. I only spent a few minutes on it.  It's not too difficult if you have control over how your div elements appear on the page.

```
<!-- The following shows your desired html structure -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #778899;
    min-width: 720px;
    max-width: 1020px;
}
#header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    height:150px;
}
#chart {
    float:left;
    height:120px;
    width:50%;
    background-color:green;
    top:150px;
}
#legend {
    float:left;
    height:230px;
    width:50%;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#info1 {
    float:right;
    height:150px;
    width:50%;
    background-color:red;
    top:150px;}
#info2 {
    float:right;        
    height:150px;
    width:50%;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;}
#info3 {
    float:right;        
    height:150px;
    width:50%;
    background-color:yellow;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:500px;margin-left:150px;margin-left:160px;">
  <div id="header">BLACK</div>
  <div id="chart">green</div>
  <div id="info1">red</div>
  <div id="legend">yellow</div>
  <div id="info2">black</div>
  <div id="info3">yellow</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[http://www.amazon.com/HTML-Utopia-Designing-Without-Tables/dp/0975240277/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1256937368&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0975240277)

is a good place to start with CSS.

Let me get you started off on the right foot, but the best way to learn this stuff is **by doing.**

I absolutely *sucked* at CSS when I first started, and now I'm fairly comfortable with it because I practice alot.

CSS

```
#header {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but ordering a book is definitely a bit much for what I want to do.  I hardly need to make csszengarden, I just need to learn how to do a couple things here and there.

Comment: CSS appears trivial but its weird.  Buying a book is necessary if you want to get past the fuddle-til-it-kinda-works stage.

Comment: I agree with Frank.  At the very least you should go over some CSS tutorials and play around with it until you get the hang of it.  Otherwise, I think things will just get frustrating and you'll never realize the full potential of CSS.  Just my $0.02 though.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div style="float:left;width:50%;">
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div id="legend"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left;width:50%;">
    <div id="info1"></div>
    <div id="info2"></div>
    <div id="info3"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option that works for me in Safari is this:

```
#header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000000;
}  

#chart, #legend {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#chart {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ff33ff;
}

#legend {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #33ffff;
}

#info1, #info2, #info3 {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 75px;
}

#info1 {
  margin-top: -150px;
  background-color: #ffff33;
}

#info2 {
  margin-top: -75px;
  background-color: #ffccff;
}

#info3 {
  background-color: #66ff66;
}
```

I chose arbitrary heights so you implementation would need to be adjusted but I think the adjustments are pretty clear from the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any HTML in your question.

The answer to your question depends on whether you want a [liquid](http://www.mardiros.net/liquid-css-layouts.html) or a static design.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, missed the Ctrl+K

Comment: This is a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: My bad, I don't yet have enough reputation to comment.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that you end up injecting layout logic into html.

Well spotted!

The fact is: CSS Positioning is not powerful to fulfill all possible layouts, especially when you are dealing with complex liquid layouts and double-especially when, as seems to be the case with your example, you want to tie the heights of unrelated, size-based-on-content elements together.

Yes, there are workarounds for many common situations, such as the ‘same height columns’ hacks and grids made out of nested floats and clears. But this almost always requires the markup to be tailored to the layout. Sometimes you can hide that by thinking of ‘nice’ class names that describe how the contained elements are related; more often, you end up with nastiness like `class="left_column"`.

Simple layouts can be done with relatively few spurious wrapper divs and reorderings, so that still ends up a bit nicer than tables. But for variable-size stuff like your example appears to be, it's not really possible; what hacks do exist would end up deeper and less maintainable than just using a table. So go ahead and bung them in a table, as long as you use `table-layout: fixed` to make them stable and fast to render, and don't start nesting tables like the Netscape 4 horrors of yesteryear.

Until CSS delivers the Holy Grail of complete layout/markup independence — and that's something that CSS3 [might deliver](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid/) in a few more decades! — you will still occasionally need to use a table. There's no shame in it.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out elsewhere adding extra container divs to act as the columns is the way to go.  Whilst perhaps unappealing as you have layout logic in your HTML, this is the currently accepted practice.  And is nicer than using tables for layout.

Alternately you could take a static approach and use absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in FF, Chrome and IE8... not sure about older IE and other browsers

```
<style type="text/css">
 #container { width: 95%; height: 95%; margin: 0 auto; overflow: auto; }
 #header { height: 9%; background: #444; }
 #chart  { width: 50%; height: 70%; float: left;  background: #555; }
 #legend { width: 50%; height: 20%; float: left;  background: #666; }

 #info1  { width: 50%; height: 30%; float: right; background: #111; }
 #info2  { width: 50%; height: 30%; float: right; background: #222; }
 #info3  { width: 50%; height: 30%; float: right; background: #333; }
</style>

<div id="container">
 <div id="header">Header</div>
 <div id="chart">Chart</div>
 <div id="info1">Info 1</div>
 <div id="info2">Info 2</div>
 <div id="info3">Info 3</div>
 <div id="legend">Legend</div>
</div>
```

*Note: I had to add the overflow:auto to the container to make it work in IE.